# Angular Route not working - some thing wrong with template url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm starting with AngularJS, but Router not working on my site.

This is some config relate to my route:

Firstly, app.js:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, 
$routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

Secondly, view1.js

```
angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: '/views/view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

angular.js, app.js and view1.js are added to the index.html

ng-view is used to show the content in view1.html

this is my folder tree:

> Project
>
> ** admin
>
> ****** app.js
>
> ****** index.html
>
> ****** views
>
> ********** view1
>
> *************** view1.html
>
> *************** view1.js

Could you give me some advise to make it working??

Thanks for watching my question!

Comment: Just a sidenote here, but I'll always be surprised by the number of people starting to learn Angular 1, when Angular 2 (now even called Angular 4) has been released in September last year.

Comment: @JeremyThille I think the reason for this is because a lot of developers are new to using JS as a main web language and AngularJS has a lot of documentation. Angular 2 is currently not fully fleshed out for JS and is very typescript heavy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving your configuration all to one `config`. Also there is no need to reference myApp in your module instantiation. Another thing is make sure you have angularjs route file in your index.html. The following will work.

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: '/views/view1/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i'll try :)